# illegalClassFormatException using Jacoco | Springboot - GraphQL

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am working on a **Springboot project and using GraphQL** for exposing endpoints.
For code coverage, I am trying to use **Jacoco** Maven dependency but facing the exception while executing `"mvn test"`.

- JDK 11
- Jacoco 0.8.5

  ```
    <plugin><groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>0.8.5</version>
             <executions>
               <execution>
                   <goals>
                      <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>report</goal></goals>
                </execution>
               </executions>
     </plugin>
  ```

I've attached the screenshot. I checked multiple links but nothing helped. *(Complete Stacktrace can be found on the [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tvhWI4iR32ZR_GnodsTLAgPYUPKjJ5bZ?usp=sharing))*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show complete stack trace, i.e. below part that is shown on your screenshot.
Please also specify which Java version and which JaCoCo version do you use.

Comment: @Godin I've updated the question and have added the screenshots. All the screenshots can be found on the google drive as well:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tvhWI4iR32ZR_GnodsTLAgPYUPKjJ5bZ?usp=sharing

Comment: To me based on the bottom of stacktrace `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at ClassReader.readVerificationTypeInfo` seems that bytecode of class `com/walmart/datamodel/prescriber/datamodels/PrescriberLookupResponseMethodAccess` is incorrect (see for example similar stacktrace in https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/reflectasm/issues/61) Can you provide this class file?

P.S. do you know that you can copy stacktrace as text instead of screenshots? what IMO will be a way more convenient for readers